# How to add a sequence of numbers in a string to an integer array in c?

Tags: arrays, c, split, numbers, c-strings

What I have is a string with some numbers (unknown amount but has a maximum), for example `char string[] = "12 13 14 123 1234 12345";` and I wanna add each number to an array. So let's say I have an array `int numbers[50];` and I want to add it to the array so it's like `{12, 13, 14, 123, 1234, 12345}`.

I've tried a loop through the string that uses a variable as a state machine to detect if it is reading a number but the code ended up looking like spaghetti so I just lost the way I was thinking. I cannot use `malloc()` or anything that allocates memory for this exercise.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `strtol` in a loop using the second parameter to move the pointer to the next space.

Comment: I would have liked to see the code you wrote

Answer (score 1):

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 50 };
    int numbers[N];
    
    char *s = "12 13 14 123 1234 12345";
    
    size_t  n = 0;
    char *p = s;
    
    for ( int value, pos = 0; n < N && sscanf( p, "%d %n", &value, &pos  ) == 1; p += pos )
    {
        numbers[n++] = value;
    }
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", numbers[i] );
    }
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
12 13 14 123 1234 12345
```

Comment: Minor: With `"%d %n"`  (add space), allows for after loop assessment with `*p == 0` for trailing junk but allowing trialing white-space as in `"123 456\n"`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I twill update the code.:)

Comment: T'was kind of you. ;-)

Comment: Thank you for this, could you explain the first for loop?

Comment: @DoubtLord The call of sscanf extracts a number from the string pointed to by the pointer p. The variable pos gets the value of extracted characters. This value is used to move the pointer p to point to the next number in the string.

Answer (score 0):

The state machine idea is good (albeit overkill; you only have three or four states after all).

You could use both this and Horner's Algorithm to parse the integer.

```
- set Horner accumulator to 0 and HaveNumber to 0 (false).
- loop:
    - read character
    - if digit:
       - multiply Horner by 10
       - add the value of the digit to Horner
       - set HaveNumber to 1
       - continue
    - if HaveNumber:
         push Horner onto array
         set HaveNumber to 0
    - set Horner to 0
    - if character was a 0 instead of a space:
         break
```

This does not need memory and does not necessarily use any function call (the digit check may be done verifying the ASCII value of the digit between 0x30 and 0x39)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtok` to split string into substrings and then use `atoi` to convert that into ints.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char my_string[] = "12 23 234 2345";
    int my_array[50] = {0};
    
    char* token = strtok(my_string, " ");
    int i = 0;
    while (token)
    {
        my_array[i] = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        i++;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```